# Can we map CLR objects properties with postgresql properties without using pgName attribute

Tags: npgsql

I am trying to invoke a procedure from postgresql database using npgsql and dapper in a .net project. I am passing  a composite type parameter while calling this procedure.

The composite type properties from database has different casing with respect to the CLR object in the .net project as shown below.

```
// Composite type
public.customertype AS
(
    name text,
    email text,
    phone text,
    phonenew text
);

// Corresponding CLR object
    public class CustomerType
    {
        [PgName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [PgName("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [PgName("phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [PgName("phonenew")]
        public string PhoneNew { get; set; }
    }
```

Hence, to resolve this casing issue am using the pgName attribute suggested by npgsql documentation and this solves the issue. However, I want to know if there is an alternative to this so that I can avoid using this attribute on my CLR object.